# How do you make a horse spawner in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've looked up some ways but if have to get rid of every single dirt block around. Is there any easy way to do it? Im on a server and cheats aren't allow but they do sell spawn eggs.

Comment: A sown egg helps if you have a monster spawner. In creative, if you right-click a spawn egg on a spawner, it will convert to a spawner for that type of mob. I have never tried it in survival, and I don’t know if it works in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

A spawn egg will not interact with a spawner in survival mode. When a spawn egg is "used", it will spawn the mob adjacent to the surface of the block it was used on (emphasis mine):

> The Player can place the Spawn Egg of choice into a Monster Spawner, *before switching to Survival*, which then will spawn that Mob continuously

[Source](http://minecraftbedrock.wikia.com/wiki/Spawn_Egg)

This unfortunately means that outside of commands, there is no way to create a custom mob spawner in survival mode.

Comment: I have also tested this myself.